# I'm starting to learn WINAPI and C++ but something wrong?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

i have something going wrong with my WinMain i try to do. I'm totally noob at Windows C++ Programming, i try to learn. I follow a tutoriel to help me. But doesn't look to works!
Here is my code..

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass1";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "WindowClass1", "Our First Windowed app", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 300, 300, 500, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);

    MSG msg;

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);

        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;


    //return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{

    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        } break;

    }
}
```

When i compile, i have no error, but when i run the app, i have only the app icon in my task bar and nothing more. In the task manager, i see 2 instances of the app.

What and where i'm wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I would say, when I began learning WinAPI, I found it absolutely finicky.  Unless EVERY detail was EXACTLY correct, the code didn't work and there were no meaningful error messages.

Comment: The normal course of action is debugging. Trace your program, see what values do API functions return. Is `RegisterClassEx()` succeeding or failing? Is `CreateWindowEx()`? Is your window proc being called at all? In the future, try debugging yourself before you ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: Seva, like i said .. i start to learn. sorry if it's not a place to post question when we learn.. i've tryed to debug by myself but my knowledge are limited. So, sorry never post again a question! :D

Comment: @neimad, The most important part of the winapi you can learn is cross-referencing [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) (specifically when to call the following) with `GetLastError`. Look up every function you use and handle the return/errors accordingly. Coming with the information you get from that proves you've debugged somewhat, and if there's an error, you might be able to track it down yourself.

Comment: This is one place I think Microsoft actually does things pretty well -- it's much easier to start from a skeleton that works than try to deal with all this crap yourself, especially to start with.

Answer (score 7):

In your window procedure, `DefWindowProc` is never being called, and thus the messages you don't handle are not being handled at all. This includes some necessities for getting your window to show up and act like a normal window. A good spot for this is in the `default` case of your switch, with all other cases having the necessary return values for that message:

```
switch (message) {
    case SOME_MESSAGE:
        //...
        return 0;

    case SOME_OTHER_MESSAGE:
        //...
        return 1; //not all messages should return 0; check each one's docs

    default: //all unhandled messages
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Turn up your warning level. You should get the following (on GCC at least, I'm sure MSVC has something similar):

> warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Comment: exacly.. lol my tutorial never told me about defwindowproc.. wow! i need to change tutorial! hehe

Comment: @neimad, http://winprog.org/tutorial worked for me. I'm not sure where it is in the standings, but it's where I started personally.

Comment: it's a pdf a friend give me! It suppose to get all what we need to start in C++ WinAPI! yeah right! hehe

Answer (score 4):

You missed return value in WindowProc. Don't ignore compiler warnings...

```
return ::DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
```

Comment: thanks .. like i said .. my tutorial sucks.. never talked about this return.. yeah now everything works! thanks again!